# Unable to use variables of property file in webdriver command

Tags: java, selenium, properties, junit, webdriver

In below code, I am trying to open a website http://www.rareskillsltd.com/ using Firefox Browser. This site has been defined as a variable (site) in Conf.properties file. I am able to print this value using code System.out.println(conf.getProperty("site")); and it prints correctly but when I use the same attribute to open the website using code driver.get(conf.getProperty("site")); it doesn't work. 
In the same code if I hardcode the website (driver.get("http://www.rareskillsltd.com/");) it works fine.

Could you please help me with the same. :
Below is the code I am using

```
package rsltest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Assume;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import rslinit.Init;;
public class test1 extends Init {

    @Test
    public void testLog() throws Exception{
    initialization();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("in testLog");
    System.out.println(conf.getProperty("site"));
    //driver.get("http://www.rareskillsltd.com/");
    driver.get(conf.getProperty("site"));

    //System.out.println(path.getProperty("contact"));
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath(path.getProperty("contact"))).click();

    }   
}
```

and the output of the above code is :

```
in testLog
"http://www.rareskillsltd.com/"
```

Comment: Show us your "Conf" code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have the site value `http://www.rareskillsltd.com/` within double quotes in the property file.

```
site="http://www.rareskillsltd.com/"
```

Remove them. It should be

```
site=http://www.rareskillsltd.com/
```